# Items are duplicating each time I start the app in a ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

**ListView** is populating with the items from the **Cursor** wich I pass in the **SimpleCursorAdapter**, but each time I open the application these items are re-added to the listview increasing it continously. When I use **SimpleAdapter**, i do something like this:

```
static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> foobar = new 
                                          ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
   SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, foobar, R.layout.list_item, String[] from, int[] to);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Doing next, solve my problem:

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
       foobar.removeAll(foobar);
    }
```

But now, I don't want to delete the database content,so how to solve it if I have a **SimpleCursorAdapter**? like this one:

```
> SimpleCursorAdapter myadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, String[] from, int[] to);
```

I have tried **setListAdapter(null)** or **cursor.close()**,and many others, but no efect...

Now, these hapen when I exit the application using "back" button of the device. If I press "home" button, when I came back I have the same number of items.So the list is duplicating every time I exit with "back" button.

Solved thanks to Kaediil's answer.The commented lines is what I have improved. The hole class:

```
public class DataBaseActivity extends ListActivity {

 DataBaseMethods dbmet; //is the class that handle database and auxiliar methods working on it

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    dbmet = new DataBaseMethods(this);
    Cursor mycursor= dbmet.getItems(); // 1. add new cursor


    try{
            if(!mycursor.moveToFirst()){   //2.check if there are items in the database
        dbmet.addItems("Daniel","Son","Karate-kid");
        dbmet.addItems("Silv", "Stalone", "Terminator");
        dbmet.addItems("foo", "bar", "buz");
            } //
            showDatabaseContent();
    }

    finally{
        dbmet.close();
    }
}


public void showDatabaseContent(){

     DataBaseMethods dbmet = new DataBaseMethods(this);
    try{

        Cursor cursor = dbmet.getItems();
        SimpleCursorAdapter myadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_list, cursor, dbmet.FROM, TO);
        setListAdapter(myadapter);
    }
    finally{
        dbmet.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: your problem is not present in the code you presented .. I guess your data is "hard-coded" and you are probably simply saving it to your database every time. look at your db helper class or where you call its methods under onCreate.. if you cant find it post the code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, this line is suspect:

> If does it matter, I'm populating the database in this activity's onCreate(), but I have tried to populate it also from other activity and I get the same behaviour for the listview.

In the populating of the database call do you check to see if the database is already populated?

It sounds like you just keep adding more copies to the DB that the cursor is pointing to.

Comment: No, I don't ....Seeing your reply, I have tried to use something with ` if cursor.isNull(0)` but every time was generating an index exception, whatever i put. Any advice, please?

Comment: Ok, looking at the edited code you are definitely going to just keep adding to the database.  You an (although it is somewhat inefficient) do this:     Cursor cursor = dbmet.getItems();
if(!cur.moveToFirst())  That call to moveToFirst will return false if it is empty.

Comment: It works :)) To be honestly I wanted to try this earlier but I was discouraged by the `cur.isNull(0)` and I didn't try it anymore,thinking that it almost same thing.Thank! I will update the question with some comments, that the solution to bemor visible.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help, don't forget to mark the question answered too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showDatabaseContent(){

     DataBaseMethods dbmet = new DataBaseMethods(this);
    try{

        Cursor cursor = dbmet.getItems();
        SimpleCursorAdapter myadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_list, cursor, dbmet.FROM, TO);
        setListAdapter(myadapter);
       -->> myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); <<----
    }
    finally{
        dbmet.close();
    }


}
```

You need to call notifyDataSetChanged() to signal the list to invalidate itself ONLY with the new data.

`NOTE:`
If the issue is from the Database class. Make sure you are not reinserting items in the database every time you start the application. I might mixed your problem, wither the items are duplicate in the listview or in the database. I'm deeply sure that you are reinserting the data every time you run the app.

Comment: Nop, doesn't solve it. I also have tried to remove `dbmet = new DataBaseMethods(this)` from this method, thinking that it is called twice. If I'm inserting every time when I start the app,be sure I would like to don't do it, but I don't know how. The only place where I'm inserting is here,`onCreate()`, if I don't add these 3 code lines I will have no data,I tested it. Any advice?